# Subquery in a left outer join

Tags: subquery, outer-join

I have been searching high and low but cannot find a simple solution that I can understand.

I have this query:

```
select * from table_A
Left Outer Join Table_B 
on  table_A.common_column = Table_B.common_column
and Table_B.column = (select max(id) from table_C where value = :BINDVARIABLE) /*Static Number*/
```

I keep getting the following error:
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are trying use a condition that should be in a WHERE clause as join between two table. Move the subquery to the WHERE clause and then you need to add a join between table_A and table_B on whatever is the common column between them, Like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_A
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_B ON table_A.common_column = table_B.common_column
WHERE Table_B.column = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_C WHERE value = :BINDVARIABLE)
```

Comment: I do understand that but i believe my problem is more complex than this. I have edited my question a little bit